# Heroku Error H10 (App crashed)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, git, heroku

My Heroku app has crashed, and all i'm getting out of the logs is Error H10 (App crashed)

```
2012-03-28T14:11:56+00:00 heroku[router]: Error H10 (App crashed) -> GET www.devsite.com/ dyno= queue= wait= service= status=503 bytes=
2012-03-28T14:11:56+00:00 heroku[nginx]: 109.145.58.15 - - [28/Mar/2012:14:11:56 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 503 607 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_7_3) AppleWebKit/535.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/17.0.963.83 Safari/535.11" www.devsite.com
```

Any idea how to draw more information out of heroku logs - or find out what is wrong?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I had a similar problem, every time I hit the server, I just got these 2 useless lines of output in the logs.

When I ran:

```
heroku restart
```

It ended up showing me more output that let me track down my issue (related to migrating to cedar) (the app was crashing on deploy it appears, never fully starting up, but not showing an error during the deploying process, as would usually occur).

Comment: Try this: heroku config:add BUILDPACK_URL=https://github.com/joelcogen/heroku-buildpack-rails-unicorn-nginx

Comment: something might have been lost in edits because it took me a minute to understand what the answer was saying but just run `heroku restart` from the commandline

Comment: If you encounter this via the rails tutorial, rebundle but as: `bundle install --without development` sqlite gem causes an issue with heroku

Answer (score 3):

According to their Developer documentation:

> Check your app’s backtrace in the logs to find out what you need to do to fix the problem.

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/errors

Comment: In my case, the logs did not provide any useful information - just "App crashed". `heroku restart` fixed it for me. It was probably a Heroku issue. More details on the error here: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/error-codes#h10-app-crashed

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issues and it was related to the dynos. H10 error.

Just run:

`heroku restart`

Fixed it for me!

Comment: Your answer is right and this was also my fix, but an earlier answer essentially captures this.

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar problem and the error was masked, running a rails c on heroku gave us the reason for the crash